# Why double colons don't seem to work for pseudo-elements in Google Chrome on a Macbook

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome, pseudo-element

I have encountered what I think is a weird problem, and I hope someone here knows something about it. I am a code school instructor using a curriculum that I did not put together. I also have a MacBook and a PC. The first project in the curriculum is a practice website that uses article tags for each page and the before pseudo-element to add in the background images with an opacity overlay. Now I've used this curriculum for a few years now, and I don't recall this being a problem until the beginning of this year, but when I load the site in Google Chrome on my MacBook the background images don't work. They work in Safari and Firefox on my MacBook, and they work in Google Chrome on my PC.

After a bit of fooling around I think I found out the cause. I've been teaching the students that we are supposed to use double colons :: with the before and after pseudo-elements, and that's what we've done. Last night I changed them back to one colon : and the problem seemed to disappear. But I'm wondering what is going on with this bug, why it seems to be there only for Chrome and only when used on a MacBook. I'm looking for any information related to this.

I don't know if the code will help, but here is the HTML and the desktop CSS. I am leaving out the mobile CSS because it doesn't appear relevant. Unfortunately I don't know how to put an image file on here, but if someone else does I will post it. In the meantime, if you want to download a working copy with the images and such, my github repo is [here.](https://github.com/dtarvin/twinfeats-software)

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TwinFeats Software</title>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Indie+Flower&family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/standard.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/mobile.css" media="screen and (orientation: portrait)">
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="mobile-nav" href="#nav">
            <img src="./images/menu.png" alt="" id="menu">
        </a>
        <nav id="nav">
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
            <a href="#services">Services</a>
            <a href="#apps">Applications</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </nav>
        <article id="about">
            <h1>About Us</h1>
            <p>
                Twin brothers Kent & Kevin Smotherman founded TwinFeats Software in 1983 with a simple premise:
            Free software for a free world. From the beginnings on the Commodore 64 to today's Android apps, that
            vision has never wavered.
            </p>
            <div class="photobox">
                <div class="stage">
                    <figure class="cube">
                        <img class="front" src="./images/kent-solo-chess.jpg" alt="">
                        <img class="back" src="./images/computer.jpg" alt="">
                        <img class="left" src="./images/kayak.jpg" alt="">
                        <img class="right" src="./images/tacos.jpg" alt="">
                    </figure>
                    <figcaption>Kent Smotherman</figcaption>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Kent Smotherman has 38 years of professional development experience using over a
                dozen programming languages. He enjoys teaching web development, chess, and
                petting the family cat, Solo (obviously), though he is not a Bond villain.
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="photobox">
                <div class="stage">
                    <figure class="cube">
                        <img class="front" src="./images/kevin.jpg" alt="">
                        <img class="back" src="./images/cards.jpg" alt="">
                        <img class="left" src="./images/kevin-grill.jpg" alt="">
                        <img class="right" src="./images/kevin1.jpg" alt="">
                    </figure>
                    <figcaption>Kevin Smotherman</figcaption>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Kevin Smotherman has 30 years of professional development experience. His current
                role is as Lead/Advisory Software Development Engineer at CSG International. His
                favorite day of the year is Groundhog Day. No one knows why.
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
        <img src="./images/c64.jpg" alt="">
        <article id="services">
            <h1>Services</h1>
            <p>
                TwinFeats Software creates innovative, custom web applications which will meet and exceed expectations.
            We will work with you to fully understand your needs, but more than that - your data. Web applications are
            all about data, and without deeply understanding the needs of your data, your web application will suffer.
            </p>
            <h2>Web application? Huh?</h2>
            <p>
                Web sites are static. The content they display doesn't change dynamically. A web application is a web site
            powered by a database. Facebook is a great example of a web application - the data shown varies by user and
            can change every single second.
            </p>
            <img src="./images/kidjuice.jpg" alt="" class="bonus-img">
        </article>
        <img src="./images/www.jpg" alt="">
        <article id="apps">
            <h1>Applications</h1>
            <div class="sidebar">
                <img src="./images/dand.JPG" alt="">
                <img src="./images/deckbldr.gif" alt="">
                <img src="./images/kidjuice.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>
                    We've written so many applications in the last 35+ years that we have literally lost count! Applications
                like our FreedomWare line of games for the Commodore 64 are long gone, as are our productivity suite for
                GEOS on the C64 and Amiga.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Ever use WebEx, GotoMeeting, or Zoom teleconferencing software? We wrote our own back in the 90s for not
                just conferencing, but online learning. Our Android applications range from custom games to productivity
                tools. Web sites and web applications? We've done 'em by the dozens. 
                </p>
                <p>
                    As we like to say, if we can't do it at TwinFeats Software, its a hardware problem!
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">
                <img src="./images/firefly.png" alt="">
                <img src="./images/gradebook.png" alt="">
                <img src="./images/capture.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <img src="./images/webappdev.jpg" alt="" class="bonus-img">
        </article>
        <img src="./images/apps.jpg" alt="">
        <article id="contact">
            <h1>Contact</h1>
            <div>
                <a href="mailto:kent@twinfeats.com"><img src="./images/email.png" alt="">Email</a>
                <a href="tel:402-718-5784"><img src="./images/phone-call-1.png" alt="">(402) 718-5784</a>
                <a href="https://facebook.com/TwinFeats"><img src="./images/facebook.png" alt="">Facebook</a>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/TwinFeats"><img src="./images/twitter.png" alt="">Twitter</a>
            </div>
        </article>
        <img src="./images/contactbg.jpg" alt="">
        <article id="home">
            <div class="vertical-container">
                <div class="title">TwinFeats</div>
                <div>
                    <img class="logo" src="./images/logo.png" alt="logo">
                </div>
                <div class="title">Software</div>
                <p class="tagline">Free software for a free world</p>
                <div id="bonus">
                    <p>TwinFeats Software is twin brothers Kent &amp; Keith Smotherman.</p>
                    <p>&copy; 2019 TwinFeats Software, all rights reserved.</p>
                    <p>402.555.5555</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-oP6HI9z1XaZNBrJURtCoUT5SUnxFr8s3BzRl+cbzUq8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the standard.css file:

```
html {
    font-size: 16pt;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
nav {
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    font-size: larger;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
}
a {
    color: #f0f0f0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#home {
    background-image: url("../images/background.jpg");
    left: 0;
}
.logo {
    width: 9ch;
}
.title, .logo {
    font-family: "Indie Flower", sans-serif;
    font-size: 3em;
}
.tagline {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.photobox {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 1em;
}
.photobox img {
    width: 22ch;
}
article {
    padding-top: 4rem;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 20vw;
    padding-right: 20vw;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -100vw;
    transition: left 0.5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 2;
}
.photobox > :last-child {
    text-align: left;
}
.photobox figure {
    font-size: .6em;
    /* margin-left: 0; */
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: .3rem;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    /* margin-right: 1em; */
    /* margin-bottom: 2em; */
    /* margin: .3rem 1em 2em 0; */
}
figcaption {
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    font-size: 0.5rem;
    text-align: center;
}
article::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    opacity: 0.1;
    z-index: -1;
}
#about::before {
    background-image: url("../images/c64.jpg");
}
#services::before {
    background-image: url('../images/www.jpg');
}
#apps::before {
    background-image: url('../images/apps.jpg');
}
#services p, #apps p {
    text-align: left;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
#apps h1 {
    grid-area: header;
}
#apps > .content {
    grid-area: main;
}
#apps > div:nth-of-type(1) {
    grid-area: sidebar-left;
    padding-right: 1.5em;
    text-align: right;
}
#apps > div:nth-of-type(3) {
    grid-area: sidebar-right;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    text-align: left;
}
#apps > .sidebar > img {
    height: 20vh;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
#apps {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
        "header header header header header header"
        "sidebar-left main main main main sidebar-right"
        "sidebar-left main main main main sidebar-right"
        "sidebar-left main main main main sidebar-right"
        "sidebar-left main main main main sidebar-right"
        "sidebar-left main main main main sidebar-right";
}
#contact::before {
    background-image: url("../images/contactbg.jpg");
}
#contact img {
    height: 1.5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-bottom: 0.25em;
    padding-right: 0.25em;
}
#contact > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: calc(2em + 12ch);
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: left;
}
#contact a {
    color: #303030;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
nav > a:hover {
    color: cyan;
}
nav > a {
    transition: color .5s;
}
#home img.logo:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
#home img.logo {
    transition: transform 1s;
}
#contact a img {
    transition: transform .25s;
}
#contact a:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}
article + img {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -100vw;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: 3; 
}
@keyframes animate-img {
    0% {
        left: -100vw;
    }
    40% {
        left: 0;
    }
    60% {
        left: 0;
    }
    100% {
        left: -100vw;
    }
}
article:target + img {
    animation-name: animate-img;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
article:target {
    left: 0;
}
article:target ~ #home {
    left: -100vw;
}
.stage {
    perspective-origin: 50% 0;
    width: 22ch;
    margin-right: 1.5em;
}
.stage .cube {
    width: 22ch;
    height: 22ch;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
    animation: rotate 10s infinite linear;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
.cube > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.cube:hover {
    animation-play-state: running !important;
}
.stage .front {
    transform: translateZ(11ch);
}
.stage .back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(11ch);
}
.stage .top {
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(11ch);
}
.stage .bottom {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(11ch);
}
.stage .left {
    transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(11ch);
}
.stage .right {
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(11ch);
}
@keyframes rotate {
    0% {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    5% {
        transform: rotateY(90deg);
    }
    25% {
        transform: rotateY(90deg);
    }
    30% {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    55% {
        transform: rotateY(270deg);
    }
    75% {
        transform: rotateY(270deg);
    }
    80% {
        transform: rotateY(360deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
#mobile-nav, #mobile-trigger, #bonus, .bonus-img {
    display: none;
}
```

I appreciate everyone's help!

Comment: `::before` definitely works on Chrome on a MacBook, and from what I can see from your files, the code is all working fine on Chrome on MacBook. (I downloaded it all from GitHub.) I'm not sure what to suggest other than to restart Chrome / clear cache etc!